# Weird Behaviour Salesforce formula

Tags: formula

I am trying to create a formula that will display various emojis (red, yellow and green) depending of the time a lead spent into various stages. For example, if the lead is in the stage "assigned" since more than 10 days, the formula should display a red (or yellow it does really matter for my question here).

I created this formula:

```
IF(
  AND(
    NOT(ISNULL(Nurturing_End_Date__c)), 
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Nurturing"),
    DATETIMEVALUE(Nurturing_End_Date__c) <= NOW()
  ), 
  "",
  IF(
    AND(
      NOT(ISNULL(Tracking_Assigned_Date__c)),
      ISPICKVAL(Status, "Assigned"),
      DATETIMEVALUE(Tracking_Assigned_Date__c) <= NOW() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    ), 
    "",
    IF(
      AND(
        NOT(ISNULL(Tracking_Assigned_Date__c)),
        ISPICKVAL(Status, "Assigned"),
        DATETIMEVALUE(Tracking_Assigned_Date__c) <= NOW()
      ),
      "",
      IF(
        AND(
          NOT(ISNULL(Tracking_Contacted_Date__c)),
          ISPICKVAL(Status, "Contacted"),
          DATETIMEVALUE(Tracking_Contacted_Date__c) <= NOW() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        ), 
        "",
        IF(
          AND(
            NOT(ISNULL(Tracking_Contacted_Date__c)),
            ISPICKVAL(Status, "Contacted"),
            DATETIMEVALUE(Tracking_Contacted_Date__c) <= NOW()
          ), 
          "",
          IF(
            AND(
              NOT(ISNULL(Tracking_Qualification_R1_Date__c)),
              ISPICKVAL(Status, "Qualification_R1_scheduled"),
              DATETIMEVALUE(Tracking_Qualification_R1_Date__c) <= NOW() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
            ),
            "",
            IF(
              AND(
                NOT(ISNULL(Tracking_Qualification_R1_Date__c)),
                ISPICKVAL(Status, "Qualification_R1_scheduled"),
                DATETIMEVALUE(Tracking_Qualification_R1_Date__c) <= NOW()
              ),
              "",
              IF(
                AND(
                  NOT(ISNULL(Tracking_Qualified_R2_Date__c)),
                  ISPICKVAL(Status, "Qualified_R2_scheduled"),
                  DATETIMEVALUE(Tracking_Qualified_R2_Date__c) <= NOW() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
                ),
                "",
                IF(
                  AND(
                    NOT(ISNULL(Tracking_Qualified_R2_Date__c)),
                    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Qualified_R2_scheduled"),
                    DATETIMEVALUE(Tracking_Qualified_R2_Date__c) <= NOW()
                  ),
                  "",
                  ""
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

The issue is that the formula show no error but when I populate specific values in the corresponding fields (for example Tracking_Assigned_Date__c), the layout of the lead start bugging showing this error: ui.services.connection.api.PartnerConnectionException: INVALID_DATE_FORMAT: Invalid DateTime [image](see screen cap).

I tried to understand the issue myself but as the formula looks fine to me, I don't get the error message.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe I forgot to mention that the field I am referring to are "date time" fields (all of them

Comment: start with a simpler formula, get it to work, then add each additional if/else clause

Comment: The first thing that strikes me as odd is why are you using `DATETIMEVALUE()` if the fields are already of type `Datetime`? That function is generally used to convert something of type _`String`_ into a Datetime.